alembic socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
When I trying run alembic upgrade head or alembic revision --autogenerate I recieve this error:
https://pastebin.com/L6QqYXRE (Full Traceback)
I think problem in my .env variables:
.env:
POSTGRES_HOST=host.docker.internal
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

settings.py:
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    BOT_TOKEN: str
    BOT_WEBHOOK_URL: str
    CRYPTO_PAY_TOKEN: str
    CRYPTO_WEBHOOK_URL: str
    POSTGRES_HOST: str
    POSTGRES_PORT: int
    POSTGRES_USER: str
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: str
    POSTGRES_DB: str
    WEBHOOK_URL: str


    @property
    def db_url(self) -> str:
        protocol='postgresql+asyncpg'
        user_data = f'{self.POSTGRES_USER}:{self.POSTGRES_PASSWORD}'
        server_data = f'{self.POSTGRES_HOST}:{self.POSTGRES_PORT}'
        return f'{protocol}://{user_data}@{server_data}/{self.POSTGRES_DB}'

    class Config:
        env_file = '.env'

env.py (alembic):
config = context.config

if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

target_metadata = Base.metadata

config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', settings.db_url)

# ...

In env.py I get url from settings and set it as sqlalchemy.url
If I change host.docker.internal to 0.0.0.0 or localhost I get the same error.
It happends after I firstly run docker compose up and now I can not use alembic even if use only container with postgres.
